# Anchor tag issue with width

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with styling the top bar for a website. I want all of the anchor tags to be equally distributed throughout the entirety of the screen. There are four anchor tags, so I thought that by making the width of each tag 25%, they would each take up a quarter of the block. They should theoretically all be in one line, but the very last one gets moved down. I have no clue what's causing this to happen and hope I'll be able to get some help. Thank you!

html code:

```
<div class="navbar">
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="lessons.php">Lessons</a>
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
<a href="login.php">Login</a>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%; /* Four equal-width links. If you have two links, use 50%, and 33.33% for three links, etc.. */
  text-align: center; /* If you want the text to be centered */
}
```

Comment: By the way. In your first rule *, you can simply use margin: 0 instead of four rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the padding defined in `.navbar a` that causes the offset. You can add a `box-sizing: border-box` to the rule to avoid this effect (content will shrink instead of container expanding to fit the padding). Or, better i think, use flexbox :

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex
}

.navbar a {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center; /* If you want the text to be centered */
}
```

The `display: flex` will initialize flexbox on navbar container and the `flex: 1` in anchor will tell browser to give equal width to all elements.

A quick fiddle to explain (case 1 & 2 can be easily fixed with `box-sizing`) :

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 
 .item-no-flex {
   width: 25%;
   padding: 3px;
   border: 1px dashed #000;
   float: left;   
 }
 
 .item-ib {
   width: 25%;
   padding: 3px;
   border: 1px dashed #000;
   display: inline-block
 }
 
 .container-flex {
   width: 200px;
   display: flex;
   border: 1px solid #000
 }
 
 .item-flex {
   width: 25%;
   padding: 3px;
   flex: 1;
   border: 1px dashed #000;
 }
```

```html
<p>Float</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-no-flex">1</div>
  <div class="item-no-flex">2</div>
  <div class="item-no-flex">3</div>
  <div class="item-no-flex">4</div>
</div>

<p style="clear:both">Inline-block</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-ib">1</div>
  <div class="item-ib">2</div>
  <div class="item-ib">3</div>
  <div class="item-ib">4</div>
</div>

<p style="clear:both">Flexbox</p>
<div class="container-flex">
  <div class="item-flex">1</div>
  <div class="item-flex">2</div>
  <div class="item-flex">3</div>
  <div class="item-flex">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your code and using flexbox.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a href="lessons.php">Lessons</a>
  <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
  <a href="login.php">Login</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

This should distribute the links equally across the page with space around each link, regardless of screen width.